# How to upload image to mongodb using React in Meteor.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

Hy there,
I'm trying to upload images to my react-meteor application, but I have no experience and my code is too buggy.
Can you show me the way how to upload images from my react application to the mongo local collection in meteor.js please?

PS: I tried to use express but it doesn't work with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package: Meteor Files at https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files

Comment: I will try this one, Thank you so much